# How to use the clone function in pg-mem?

Tags: postgresql, pg-promise, pg-mem

I'm trying to use [pg-mem](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-mem) with the [pg-promise adapter](https://github.com/oguimbal/pg-mem/wiki/Libraries-adapters) for testing my database layer.

Initially I've tried fetching a fresh database for each test:

```js
import { newDb } from 'pg-mem';
import {createTables} from './database';

export const getTestDatabase = async () => {
  const database = await newDb().adapters.createPgPromise();
  database.connect();
  await createTables(database);
  return database;
};
```

But then I get an annoying warning about duplicate database connections for each test:

```
WARNING: Creating a duplicate database object for the same connection
```

So I tried to use the `backup` and `restore` functions to return a restored database for each test:

```js
import { newDb } from 'pg-mem';
import {createTables} from './database';

const mock = newDb();
let backup;
let database;
let databaseInitialized = false;

export const getTestDatabase = async () => {
  if (!databaseInitialized) {
    databaseInitialized = true;
    database = await mock.adapters.createPgPromise();
    database.connect();
    await createTables(database);
    backup = mock.backup();
  } else {
    backup.restore();
  }
  return database;
};
```

This mostly works, except that some of my tests alter the schema, at which point I get this error:

```
Context: Error: You cannot restore this backup: schema has been changed since this backup
has been created => prefer .clone() in this kind of cases
```

How do I use the `clone` function? I can't find any documentation.

What's the correct way to solve my problem?

Comment: Use a singleton pattern, to avoid `Creating a duplicate database...` warning, i.e. do not do re-create the database on each `getTestDatabase` call, reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `database.synchronize()` before calling `mock.backup()`.